# Using the same form more than once per page with AJAX callbacks

Tags: 8, forms

I have a small email signup form made from extending FormBase that takes an email address and submits it to a mail service. I need to change the submit to AJAX so I can flash a success or error message.

I want to show this form more than once on a page. Once in a CTA near the top of the page, and there is a slightly different styled version in the footer.

When I added `#ajax` to the submit button, only one instance of the form seems to be affected. Here is the whole form:

```
$info = $form_state->getBuildInfo();

$form['#prefix'] = '<section class="hl__single-input-form">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</section>';
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'hl__single-input-form__form';

$form['title'] = [
  '#type' => 'label',
  '#for' => 'edit-email-address',
  '#title' => 'Stay in the know',
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => [
      'hl__label',
      'hl__label--inline',
    ],
  ],
];

if (!empty($info['args'][0]) && $info['args'][0] == "show_tagline") {
  $form['tagline'] = [
    '#markup' => '<div class="hl__single-input-form__helper-text">Sign up for email updates from MySite</div>',
  ];
}

$form['email_address'] = [
  '#type' => 'email',
  '#size' => NULL,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#attributes' => [
    'placeholder' => $this->t('Email'),
    'class' => [
      'hl__input',
      'hl__input--inline',
      'js-is-required',
    ],
    'data-twig-suggestion' => 'newsletter_signup_email',
  ],
  '#prefix' => '<div class="hl__single-input-form__input-group">',
];

$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Sign up'),
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => [
      'hl__button',
      'hl__button--small',
      'hl__button--inline',
    ],
    'data-twig-suggestion' => 'newsletter_signup_submit',
  ],
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#ajax' => [
    'wrapper' => 'hl__single-input-form',
  ]
];
```

The block in the footer that pulls the form just has this build method:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return ['form' => $this->formBuilder->getForm('\Drupal\harlib_newsletter_signup\Form\NewsletterSignup')];
  }
```

The preprocess for the Paragraph that outputs the form when being themed:

```
$variables['signup_form'] = \Drupal::service('form_builder')->getForm('\Drupal\harlib_newsletter_signup\Form\NewsletterSignup', "show_tagline");
```

How can I support having this form on the page more than once, both with the same AJAX action on submit? Also, how can I avoid overwriting the wrong wrapper with an AjaxCommand?

edit: validateForm method:

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $email_value = $form_state->getValue('email_address');
if (empty($email_value) || !\Drupal::service('email.validator')->isValid($email_value)) {
  $form_state->setError($form['email_address'], $this->t('Please enter a valid email address.'));
}

if (mailchimp_is_subscribed('XXXXXXX', $email_value, TRUE)) {
  $form_state->setError($form['email_address'], $this->t('You are already subscribed to our newsletter.'));
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class property for a sub id and append it to the form id:

```
class MyForm extends FormBase {

  public $sub_id = '0';

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_form_' . $this->sub_id;
  }

  ...
}
```

You can append this sub id to the wrapper as well, if you want to have different wrappers for each form:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $wrapper = 'ajax-wrapper-' . $this->sub_id;
    // use $wrapper for #ajax and div container in buildForm()
    ...
  }
```

Then set a different sub id for each instance of the form.

For example in a block the first instance:

```
$form = \Drupal::classResolver()->getInstanceFromDefinition('Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyForm');
$form->sub_id = '1';
$build['form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
```

and the second in preprocess:

```
$form = \Drupal::classResolver()->getInstanceFromDefinition('Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyForm');
$form->sub_id = '2';
$variables['form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
```

Comment: This was the road I started down, but didn't change getFormId. Let me try this.

Comment: This might have me on the right path, but how can I return an error from the validateForm method? Nothing is coming through. Updated OP.

Comment: This shouldn't be specific to this topic about multiple forms, I've managed to return validation errors to the correct form instance.

Comment: I’m not getting them at all, weird. I’ll open a new question.

Comment: Actually, I think I have been running in circles due to this. Now everything seems to work fine. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1342066#comment-12433457